# Suggestions on plugins i can use to make a fixed overlay at the bottom of my website.?

Tags: jquery-ui

**what plugin can i use to make an overlay box  that is fixed on the  bottom of the screen even while scrolling ?Any other helpful suggestion will be appreciated?**

Comment: It would be easiest to just write a bit of CSS. Also possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35990304/how-to-position-overlay-fixed-div-to-the-center-with-css

Comment: i felt so foolish why didnt i think of this.Thank you